# TFS Global Cache

Tags: caching, tfs

I am using TFS recently. I am developing an electron application. So while running my application, I am stori ng some data in my local workspace files . But I want to store this globally so that every others can also access it even before it is checked in. Something need to behave as global cache in TFS. So is there any solution for global caching in TFS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have pending changes that are not ready for check in but you need to share them with another team member. If this is the case, you can [create a shelveset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets) by follow the steps below:

1. In the **Pending Changes** page of Team Explorer, make sure that the changes you want to shelve are listed in the **Included Changes** section.
2. Choose the **Shelve** link.
3. Type a name for the shelveset and choose the Shelve button.

[image]

Then other team members can find a shelveset and work with it.